# change font size and color for scrape data in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a scrape page for this link http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/U11/company-people in ionic code.

The problem is the output for the **heading** that scrape is **too large**. I want to **change the font size and the color.**

As observe in the picture, **'Key People United Overseas Bank Ltd.' and Board of Directors'** font size is large. I want to reduce it and change to blue color font.

[image]

However, from the html code, **'Key People United Overseas Bank Ltd.' and Board of Directors'** is scrape from the website and unable to change the color and font size. I try with `style="font-size:300%;color:#AAAFFF;"` unable to change the size and color for **'Key People United Overseas Bank Ltd.' and Board of Directors'** , but change for the small font below it.

Below is my html code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Company">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll>
    <h3 style="margin: 10px;">Company Info</h3>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="companyInfo"></div>
    <h3 style="margin: 10px;">Description</h3>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="companyDescription"></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px;font-size:300%;color:#AAAFFF;" ng-bind-html="keyPeople"></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="averageGrowthRates"></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px;" ng-bind-html="ownership"></div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

scrape with angularjs code as below.

I believe the words I want to reduce the size is directly scrape and seems unable to reduce its size in html.

```
.controller("companyOwnershipCtrl",function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$state,$cashDataFactory){


  $ionicLoading.show();

  $http.get("http://vinus.johnapi.com/wsjapi?url=http://quotes.wsj.com/SG/U11/company-people")
  .success(function(response){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();

    tmp.body.innerHTML = response;

    //Company Info
    var companyInfo1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_contact")[0].children;
    var companyInfo2 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_overview_data cr_data")[0].children;

    $scope.companyInfo = "<div class='cr_profile_contact'>"+companyInfo1[0].innerHTML+"</div>";
    $scope.companyInfo += "<div class='cr_overview_data cr_data'>"+companyInfo2[0].innerHTML+"</div>";

    //Description
    var description1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_description_full cr_expand")[0].children;
    $scope.companyDescription = "<p>"+description1[0].innerHTML+"</p>";

    //Key People
    var keyPeople1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_people module")[0].children;
    $scope.keyPeople = "<div class='cr_profile_people module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+keyPeople1[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data cr_board'>"+keyPeople1[1].innerHTML+"</div></div>";

    //Average Growth Rates
    var growth = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_growth module")[0].children;
    var growth1 = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_insider module")[0].children;
    $scope.averageGrowthRates = "<div class='cr_profile_growth module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+growth[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth[1].innerHTML+"</div></div>";
    $scope.averageGrowthRates += "<div class='cr_profile_insider module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+growth1[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth1[1].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+growth1[2].innerHTML+"</div></div>";

    //ownership
    var ownership = tmp.body.getElementsByClassName("cr_profile_ownership module")[0].children;
    $scope.averageGrowthRates += "<div class='cr_profile_ownership module'><div class='mod_headerBox'>"+ownership[0].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+ownership[1].innerHTML+"</div><div class='cr_data'>"+ownership[2].innerHTML+"</div></div>";
  }).error(function(error){

    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log(error.data);

  });
```